# Output of df contradicts output of du?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, suse

When I run the `df -h` command while SSH'd into my SUSE Linux box I get the following output:

[image]

`/dev/sdt1`, with a capacity of 512G, is mounted on `/usr/sap`

However, if I cd to `usr/sap/<HANA server ID>/HDB00/backup` and run `du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr` I get:
[image]

Which indicates I have 2.0 TB of data at this location. How can `/usr/sap` have a capacity of 512G while `usr/sap/<HANA server ID>/HDB00/backup` is storing 2.0 TB of data? Note that `/dev/md125` from the first screenshot has a capacity of 2.0 TB and is completely filled, so I suspect that it is somehow involved here.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `/dev/md125` is mounted either at `usr/sap/<HANA server ID>/HDB00/backup` or somewhere within that folder. If you would like to find out for sure you can run

```
findmnt /dev/md125
```

Under `TARGET` you will likely see a directory within the `usr/sap/<HANA server ID>/HDB00/backup` folder.

Otherwise it's also possible that the md device is mounted elsewhere and there is a symlink to it within the `backup` directory but this seems unlikely to me because `du` is set to not dereference symlinks by default. To confirm you could run `du -P` which will not follow any symlinks (but again this should be the default behavior on most systems)

**Edit:**

Based on your comment that `findmnt /dev/md125` outputs only `/hana/shared` I am inclined to return to my symlink hypothesis. It occurred to me that any part of the full `/usr/sap/<HANA server ID>/HDB00/backup` path could be a symlink, so you may want to check those folders with an `ls -l` just as a quick sanity check (since the next command may take a while to complete).

Otherwise you may want to search your full /usr/sap directory for a symlink to your /hana/shared folder with something like this

```
find /usr/sap -type l -exec stat {} + | grep /hana/shared
```

This will find any symlinks to any folder inside of `/hana/shared` and will show you the full path to the symlink and the full path to its target within `/hana/shared`.

Comment: `findmnt /dev/md125` gives me `/hana/shared`